# Vectorization using tensors Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have tensor **x** of shape **(10,2)**
I have tensor **y** of shape **(10,)**
I have tensor **y_pred** of shape **(10,)**

I want to compute a tensor **dw** of shape **(2,1)** using the formula as follows.

Let dw1 and dw2 be the elements in tensor **dw**.
**dw1** = tf.reduce_sum(**x1** * (**y** - **y_pred**)) * (-2/n)
where ,
**x1** = 1st column of tensor x
**n** = scalar

**dw2** = tf.reduce_sum(**x2** * (**y** - **y_pred**)) * (-2/n)
where ,
**x2** = 2nd column of tensor x
**n** = scalar

**However, tensor x will have a dynamic shape.

If tensor x has a shape (10,3)

dw will have shape of (3,1)**

In ML perspective I am calculating gradients of the loss function w.r.t weights.
The loss function is MSE.

I know how to implement this using for loop.
But I don't understand how I should implement it using Vectorization ie. Not using any for loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Try the plain old [matrix multiplication](http://matrixmultiplication.xyz/):

```
x = tf.ones((10,2), dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.ones((10,1), dtype=tf.float32) * 2
y_pred = tf.ones((10,1), dtype=tf.float32) * 3
n = 3

result = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(x), y-y_pred) / (-n/2)
```

Explanation:

`tf.ones` creates a matrix for demonstration purposes. First argument marks it's shape.
the `x` has shape of 10 by 2, to multiply that by a matrix of shape 10 by 1, you need to transpose `x`.
Then you just do the matrix multiplication that does exactly what you need.

Note that `dtype=tf.float32` is necessary, without it you might get a casting error.